# Django & javascript: hidden div dynamically updated

Tags: javascript, python, django, hidden

I'm currently struggling with Django and javascript.

I have a HTML table. Each row corresponds to a Django element I load from a SQL database.

Something like this :

```
    <table>
    {% for item in list %}

        <tr tabindex="0" 
            data-toggle="popover" 
            data-trigger="focus" 
            data-popover-content=".hidden" 
            data-placement="right"
            onclick="snpTable()"
            >
            <td>{{ item.elem1 }}</td>
            <td>{{ item.elem2 }}</td>
            <td>{% for t in item.elem3_list %}
                {{t}}<br/>
                {% endfor %}
            </td>
```

Now, when I click on a row, I want to have a new table that displays all the remaining information about this item. The platform I'm working on uses bootstrap, and thanks to other SO questions I've been able to display a table when a row is clicked. 
Basically, the last case on each row contains a div, hidden by default, that contains the table. I use bootstrap's popover method to display it when the  is clicked.

```
               <div class="hidden">
                    <div class="popover-heading">
                        <!-- Just a heading with an element from the list -->
                    </div>
                    <div class="popover-body">
                        <table style="width:100%">
                            <tr><td>{{ item.elem4 }}</td></tr>
                            <tr><td>{{ item.elem5 }}</td></tr>
                            <tr><td>{{ item.elem6 }}</td></tr>
                            <tr><td>{{ item.elem7 }}</td></tr>
                            <tr><td>{{ item.elem8 }}</td></tr>
                            <tr><td>{{ item.elem9 }}</td></tr>
                            <tr><td>{{ item.elem10 }}</td></tr>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    <script>$("[data-toggle='popover']").popover('destroy'); </script>
{% endfor %}
</table>
```

Nothing fancy, right? The elements 4, 5, and so on are loaded with the rest, but only displayed when you click on the .
Well, it doesn't work. The items 1 to 3 are loaded perfectly and I have one row per item of the database. However, the table that displays when I click on those rows is always the same, no matter the element, and only displays the information of the first element.

I hope I'm clear enough. When I click on a row, I should have a popup table with additional information for each item, but I only have the information of the first item.

Here is the [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/m6tjL4Lu/) I tried to set up, which isn't really useful because django.

Can anybody help me please? I don't understand at all why the second table isn't updated for each row.

EDIT: The problem is solved ! I need to give the div a dynamic id, for instance `id="{{ item.elem1 }}"`. Then I call the JS function for each of these IDs.

Comment: Can you post your final generated Html. You can get that from page source in the browser

Comment: The problem is solved ! I need to give the div a dynamic id, for instance `id="{{ item.elem1 }}"`. Then I call the JS function for each of these IDs.